# SQL SELECT query not working - unable to find error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

The following `select` query is to search a keyword 'law' from multiple tables `tbl_books`, `tbl_author` and `tbl_books_subject`

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_books p, tbl_books_author d, tbl_books_subject m
WHERE p.title = 'law'
   OR d.author = 'law'
   OR m.subject = 'law'
LIMIT 0,30
```

This query is giving error. Please help me with it.

Comment: And whats the error?

Comment: There's no join between the tables, so you end up with a `CROSS JOIN`. The error will probably indicate "running out of space" :-)

Comment: The error is Internal Server Error.

Comment: Provide the DDL for the tables and expected result you are looking at. The question is pretty unclear.

Comment: WHere is the other coes?

Comment: internal server error sounds more like your php script is broken, not the query. (well, the query results are probably broken, but it doesn't cause 503s, php errors do)

Comment: @dnoeth can you please help me in this , INNER JOIN to be used right

Comment: "law" is a keywork which i have to search in all the three tables. Any record having this keyword must be shown.

Comment: You need to search each table individually.

Comment: We need your table constraints (PKs) to give you the right sql statement.

Comment: the primary key are id

Comment: It seems like you want a UNION.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve that in single query but you need to have some foreign key in other tables. Here check the code below.

```
SELECT b.*, ba.*, bs.* FROM tbl_books as b
    FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_books_author as ba ON ba.book_id=b.id
    FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_books_subject as bs ON bs.book_id=b.id
WHERE b.title LIKE 'law' OR ba.author LIKE 'law' OR bs.subject LIKE 'law' LIMIT 0, 30;
```

look at the query deeply you can see I have used **tbl_books.id** to make joins which should be in other tables to identify that particular records.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: To get a result where any of those columns contains 'law' you need to use `FULL OUTER JOINs` instead

Comment: @dnoeth mysql doesn't support `full outer join`. and now this 'correct' answer is horribly broken.

Comment: @pala_: So it's back to "three separate selects" :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need three separate SELECTs (and probably a wildcard search):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_books
WHERE title LIKE '%law%'
LIMIT 0,30

SELECT *
FROM tbl_books_author 
WHERE title LIKE '%law%'
LIMIT 0,30

SELECT *
FROM tbl_books_subject
WHERE title LIKE '%law%'
LIMIT 0,30
```

If you return compatible results you might UNION them:

```
SELECT 'book   ', title
FROM tbl_books
WHERE title LIKE '%law%'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'author ', author
FROM tbl_books_author 
WHERE title LIKE '%law%'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'subject', subject
FROM tbl_books_subject
WHERE title LIKE '%law%'
LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: Does LIMIT 0,30 apply to the whole query, or just the last select here?

Comment: Will there be problem if i use OR and write all together using LIKE keyword.

Comment: when i run my previous code on the top it shows, "Showing rows 0 - 29 (1759260 total, Query took 5.1206 sec)". can you please explain why it is showing this.

Comment: If "previous code" means all "three tables in one query without join" this indicates that you created a huge stupid result set by cross-joining the tables.