# Searching a keyword from multiple tables using my query ,

Tags: mysql, select, php

I want to search "law" from three tables `tbl_books`, `tbl_books_author` and `tbl_books_subject`. I am running following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_books p, tbl_books_author d, tbl_books_subject m
WHERE p.title = 'law'
OR d.author = 'law'
OR m.subject = 'law'
LIMIT 0,30;
```

When I run this query it shows on top  "Showing rows 0 - 29 (1759260 total, Query took 5.1206 sec)". can you please explain why it is showing this.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: You're essentially creating a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) involving 3 tables.. What would you expect it to return? Aren't those 3 tables supposed to be connected by foreign keys? Do you really have an author named 'Law'?

Comment: Shall i join all the tables using INNER JOIN and then run the query. All the tables are having id as the primary key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL SELECT QUERY NOT WORKING. Unable to find error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252911/sql-select-query-not-working-unable-to-find-error)

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, you are doing a Cartesian product i.e. matching all records from first table with all records from 2nd tables and with 3d table.

You probably have some foreign keys relating tables, so your query should look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_books p 
INNER JOIN tbl_books_author d ON inner_join_condition1
INNER JOIN tbl_books_subject m ON inner_join_condition2
WHERE p.title = 'law'
OR d.author = 'law'
OR m.subject = 'law'
LIMIT 0,30;
```

fill in with you inner_join_conditions between tables